# Not able to add Linux machine as agent to Jenkins controller running on Windows machine

Tags: linux, jenkins, ssh, jenkins-agent

Tried creating ssh key on Windows controller and shared public key to linux agent node. Permission on linux agent is `600` for authorized keys. Added my private key to Jenkins credential as ssh username and private key.

I have added Linux agent IP and hostname to Windows machine hosts file and vice versa.

Tried all option in dropdown for verifying the host key. No luck.

Controller: Windows. created jenkins local user and ssh key generated with that user.
Agent: Linux node. created jenkins user and ssh key copied to jenkins user.

below is the error:

```
SSHLauncher{host='********', port=22, credentialsId='7-9daf-fe34097adb71', jvmOptions='', javaPath='', prefixStartSlaveCmd='', suffixStartSlaveCmd='', launchTimeoutSeconds=60, maxNumRetries=10, retryWaitTime=15, sshHostKeyVerificationStrategy=hudson.plugins.sshslaves.verifiers.ManuallyTrustedKeyVerificationStrategy, tcpNoDelay=true, trackCredentials=true}
[06/10/21 12:49:53] [SSH] Opening SSH connection to ******* .
[06/10/21 12:49:53] [SSH] SSH host key matches key seen previously for this host. Connection will be allowed.
ERROR: Server rejected the 1 private key(s) for jenkins (credentialId:-4fc7-9daf-fe34097adb71/method:publickey)
[06/10/21 12:49:53] [SSH] Authentication failed.
Authentication failed.
[06/10/21 12:49:53] Launch failed - cleaning up connection
[06/10/21 12:49:53] [SSH] Connection closed.
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few different permissions that might be at work here, on the Linux side. You need to check the permissions on `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` and `~/.ssh`, which you have partly done already. Additionally, there may be SELinux labelling preventing access. Try the following:

```sh
chmod 700 ~/.ssh
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
restorecon -Rv ~/.ssh
```

Comment: Many thanks @Stephen badger. It worked. You saved my day.

restorecon did magic.